# How to train a TensorFlow model having branches that need to train alternately according to the data type؟

Tags: python, tensorflow

Suppose I have two data a and b, and I want to compute the similarity between them using the dot product. However, there are two types of a, a1 and a2; such that, the feature of a1 and a2 are obtained by module_a1 and module_a2 respectively. The feature of b is obtained from module_b.

My question is how can I implement OR operation that existed in the attached figure.
Please, see this image to clarify the idea.

[image: 1]

It means if the type of a is a1, use module_a1 to generate features of a in the training (i.e. use it in forward and backward propagation), else if the type is a2, use module_a2. Therefore, in some iterations, module_a1 gets trained, and in the other iterations, module_a2 gets trained.

So, could you help me, with how can I implement this idea in TensorFlow?  Thanks

Comment: Please elaborate more, on deep learning and neural network concepts. What are module_1 and 2? How do you want to approach dot product and so on? Generally speaking, I think you need to have 2 different models, train each of them separately, and after training, you can build one model of them and bring them to 1 place.

Comment: I am new to tensorflow, but would it be an idea to have each module_a multiplied by zero if it is not supposed to be used and then add the two outputs up? That way, they would both be part of the pipeline, but only affected when in use

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The modules just consist of some dense layers. but I need to make them (i.e. module _a1 and module_a2 )separately and ensure that  they are trained probably based on their corresponding data

Answer (score 0):

```
is_a1 = tf.cast(tf.equal(data_type,a1),tf.float32)

is_a2 = 1 - is_a1

module_a1 = tf.layers(input)

module_a2 = tf.layers(input)

a = tf.math.multiply(is_a1,module_a1) + tf.math.multiply(is_a1,module_a2)
```

Comment: While this may answer the question at hand, it would be helpful if you actually provided some context and explanation to accompany your code